# sql 2014 express performance issues

Tags: c++, sql-server, performance

I have a fairly large Windows application (about 10 years old, written in c++) which works with SQL2000 Express (MSDE). It operates with database pretty extensively, but doesn't have performance issues. Due to SQL2000 MSDE compatibility issues with Windows 7/8 I want to migrate the application to SQL2014 Express.

All database access code is written in t/sql and as such the application migrates to SQL2014 without any code changes and all features work as expected. Except it's so badly slow it makes no sense to use the application under SQL2014. All select/update/insert queries take about 5-20 times more time to execute.

These are connection strings that I tried:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\app;User ID=app_user;Password=password;
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\app;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

I don't convert SQL2000 database to 2014 as the application creates a new database from scratch from scripts on its first run. Nothing fails, the default DB size is 12MB, the schema is pretty well optimised.

I also tried the same under SQL2008R2 Express - it's as slow as SQL2014 Express. Tried different PCs under Windows 7/8/8.1 - all the same.

The main detail which I noticed is that when I run the application under SQL2014 the most CPU consuming process in Windows Task Manager is "Local Security Authority Process". This process doesn't appear in Task Manager at all when I run it under SQL2000 MSDE and the application runs much faster. I guess LSA may be very heavy processing my "open connection" requests, but I don't know what to do about it.

The application is written is a way that it doesn't keep connections open, but creates them on demand and then releases. I tried to run SQL 2014 service under different accounts - it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

> This process doesn't appear in Task Manager at all when I run it under SQL2000 MSDE and the application runs much faster. I guess LSA may be very heavy processing my "open connection" requests, but I don't know what to do about it.

Typically, lsass.exe (LSA) been used by IPSEC Services(PolicyAgent),
ProtectedStorage and Security Accounts Manager(SamSs)

Try to disable IPSEC Services(PolicyAgent)

Comment: Thanks Severin. I stopped the IPsec Policy Agent service and disabled it. Tried to run the SQL queries - no performance improvements. Also just in case I turned User Account Control off and tested again - no changes.